# Postgres 13 fails at the initdb stage

Tags: postgresql, centos, libpq

I've followed the official installation instructions for my Centos 7 machine:

```
# Install the repository RPM:
sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

# Install PostgreSQL:
sudo yum install -y postgresql13-server

# Optionally initialize the database and enable automatic start:
sudo /usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup initdb
sudo systemctl enable postgresql-13
sudo systemctl start postgresql-13
```

The issue comes at the **initdb** stage. Instead of getting the typical "OK" at the end of execution, I'm given nothing. After looking through the `postgresql-13-setup` script, I managed to find an ouput log at `/var/lib/pgsql/13/initdb.log`:

```
/usr/pgsql-13/bin/initdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It looks like, for whatever reason, libpq.so.5 (which is present in other past postgres installs) is missing from `/usr/pgsql-13/lib/`.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling postgres-13 multiple times now, clearing out the service, deleting all the directories, etc. This issue is only happening in this specific machine (I've installed postgres 13 in various other similar machines with no issue).

edit:

Ad requested, running:

```
/usr/pgsql-13/bin/initdb -E UTF8 /var/lib/pgsql/13/data
```

Returns the same exact error:

```
/usr/pgsql-13/bin/initdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: According to instruction here [CentOS install](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/), on CentOS 7 it should be:  `postgresql-13-setup --initdb`. Note the `--initdb`.

Comment: I don't know why the installation process mentions that command (not on the actual instructions, but right at the bottom of the page), it makes no sense to me. There is no flag on the setup script for initdb, so it does nothing when run (well, it fails to execute the script). The main installation instructions have been fine for me in many other Centos 7 machines.

Comment: For the instructions you might want to try the email at the [Contacts](https://yum.postgresql.org/contact/) page, to give the packagers a heads up. After you do an install can you run `psql`?

Comment: Try calling the following: as user `postgres`: `/usr/pgsql-13/bin/initdb -E UTF8 /var/lib/pgsql/13/data` and see if you get the same error message. [edit] the question and add the output there.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I've edited my question (the error output was the same). I'm not sure if this is relevant at all, but I was informed that a previous person attempted to install Postgres 13 and directly followed that with a data dir rsync from a local machine that runs macOS. I'm not sure if cross OS data dir rsync works (I know it works between Linux machines), but ever since then this machine has not been able to run initdb for PG13 properly... Could be completely irrelevant, but thought I should mention this.